# Insert typed []byte with gorm in mysql raises "Error 1241: Operand should contain 1 columns(s)"

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I have a model with typed `[]byte` (password-hash), which I want to save in `MySQL:5.7` using `gorm:v2`.

```golang
// this will work
type ModelRaw struct {
    Bytes   []byte
}

type Hash []byte

// this will NOT work
type ModelTyped struct {
    Bytes Hash
}

func main() {
    // Migrate database
    // Both tables will have a column `bytes` of type `longblob default:NULL`
    if err := gormDB.AutoMigrate(&ModelRaw{}, &ModelTyped{}); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // this works
    mdl1 := &ModelRaw{Bytes: []byte("random-bytes")}
    if err := gormDB.Debug().Create(mdl1).Error; err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // error here
    mdl2 := &ModelTyped{Bytes: Hash("random-bytes")}
    if err := gormDB.Debug().Create(mdl2).Error; err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

The above code results in the following `gorm` debug output:

```
2020/11/06 10:31:29 /go/src/app/main.go:47
[7.715ms] [rows:1] INSERT INTO `model_raws` (`bytes`) VALUES ('random-bytes')

2020/11/06 10:31:29 /go/src/app/main.go:53 Error 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
[0.926ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO `model_typeds` (`bytes`) VALUES ((114,97,110,100,111,109,45,98,121,116,101,115))
panic: Error 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Repo demonstrating the problem: https://github.com/Iyashi/go-gorm-bytes-test

It **worked in** `gorm:v1` and broke in `gorm:v2`.

gorm's AutoMigrate() creates mysql table column as `longblob NULL`.

Comment: Why don't you want to convert to string? GenerateFromPassword returns a byte slice, but those bytes are all printable characters.

Comment: I might be a little overreactive, but I fear that it will be a hassle if I have to convert/cast `[]byte` to `string` everytime it has to go into `mysql`. For this one case, it would be fine, but the application probably has more `[]byte`s in the future and it worked fine in `gorm:v1`, so I assume there's a better solution. If nothing helps, I'll do that, ofc.

Comment: I've implemented my `PasswordHash` type as `string` and it works, but the next `[]byte` will fail again, which is not acceptable.

Comment: What is the type you are using for byte array in mysql ?

Comment: The real question is: have you decomposed your problem to really be this: 1) _any_ `gormDB.Create(&mdl)` passes for `Model mdl` if it contains a field of type `string`, and 2) _any_ such call fails if the the same field of the model has the type `[]byte`? I mean, your question apparently has nothing to do with `bcrypt` but is rather about how `gorm` and/or the mysql driver it uses handle mapping of `[]byte` to a MySQL column the type of which we do not even know (see what @Eklavya-UpvoteDon'tSayThanks asked). So, please take your time and improve your question.

Comment: I've testet a little bit before I went to sleep, and the error happens when you create a typed `[]byte` like `type Hash []byte`. I've fixed the question and added link to example repo in github demonstrating the problem. https://github.com/Iyashi/go-gorm-bytes-test. That should also anser @Eklavya-UpvoteDon'tSayThanks 's question.

Comment: you can always implement `Scanner` and `Valuer` interfaces for your `Hash` type. Example: https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html#Scanner-Valuer

Comment: Yes, that would help me solve the issue, but I wonder why its required now. `reflect` package should easily recognize the underlying primitive `[]byte`.

Comment: Show us the SQL generated by the "working" one; I suspect it is wrong, too.

Comment: @rick-james: I added `gorm`s debug output and updated the demo repo linked in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work, you should just implement a driver.Valuer interface:

```
func (h Hash) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
  return []byte(h), nil
}
```

Then your typed data will work with Gorm v2 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The value being used must be a byte array, not an array of numbers.

One would think that `Bytes []byte` would be equivalent to `type Hash []byte` plus `Bytes Hash`, but apparently not.

Give this a try:

```
mdl2 := &ModelTyped{Bytes: []byte(Hash("random-bytes"))}
```

Or maybe

```
mdl2 := &ModelTyped{Bytes: []byte{Hash("random-bytes")}}
```

Another possibility is to get rid of `struct` in the definition of `Hash`; it seems to be causing an extra level of "structuring" in the effect.

Comment: This would force me to create separate `struct`s for any `Model` that has a `typed []byte` field just for gorm. If nothing works, so be it, but I cant believe, that it just stops working in `gorm:v2`, while the exact same code worked in `gorm:v1`

Comment: File a bug with gorm?

Comment: I think more and more that this is a bug. I'll do that.